# How to add Twig special functions in yml configuration

Tags: symfony, configuration, twig

I am trying to use jpegoptim in Symfony 2

This is my config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    functions:
        jpegoptim: { output: images/*.jpg }
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
```

When I run the program I have this error :

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "functions" under "twig"
```

What is wrong ? because, obviously the functions tag exists under twig tag normally

Note : my assetic config

```
assetic:
 debug:          %kernel.debug%
 use_controller: false
 bundles:        [DemoAsseticGestionRessourcesBundle]
 filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    jpegoptim:
         bin: %kernel.root_dir%/Ressources/bin/jpegoptim/jpegoptim.exe
    #closure:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
    yui_js:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    yui_css:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
 twig:
    functions:
    jpegoptim: { output: images/*.jpg }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Twig Configuration
assetic:
    twig:
        functions:
            jpegoptim: { output: images/*.jpg }
```

Comment: It is good but now I have Unrecognized options "jpegoptim" under "assetic.twig"

Comment: That's strange. Did you read this section from the cookbook and is the configuration the same? http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/assetic/jpeg_optimize.html